# Python Build tuples from a dictionary with key and multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to build tuples from dictionary that looks like this {key: list of values}.

```
def dictionary_tuples(key, values):
    return dict((x.key, x.value) for x in values)

graph = {'11': ['12','40','41','10'], '100': ['120','400','410','100'], '12':['11','13'], '13':['12']}
a= '11'
b = graph['11']
dictionary_tuples(a,b)
```

and it doesnt work. What I want to accomplish is to have this:
`[('11','12'), ('11','40'), ('11','41'), ('11','10')]`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a list instead of a dictionary in:

  `return dict((x.key, x.value) for x in values)`

Comment: What is key in dictionary_tuples(key, values) used for?

Comment: I said in the end what I want. For me looks like a list of tuples.

Comment: You can't have more than one value per key in a dictionary.  If you had such a dictionary `d` with multiple values for the key `k`, what would you expect to get when you called `d[k]`?

Comment: @Brionius: there *is* only one value per key, which is a *list of other nodes*. The OP wants to generate a sequence of tuples with `(key1, value1[0]), (key1, value1[1]), ..., (key1, value1[-1]), (key2, value2[0]), ..., (key2, value2[-1]), etc.`.

Comment: @Martijn Oh, sorry, misread the question - thought he was asking for a dictionary with those properties.

Comment: @Sheng is used to know the key from my graph dictionary. Because in my development if want to use it like this dictionary_tuples(current_node, current_node_neighbours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function **to pass in the graph**:

```
def dictionary_tuples(key, values):
    return [(key, item) for item in values[key]]
```

As such:

```
>>> def dictionary_tuples(key, values):
...     return [(key, item) for item in values[key]]
... 
>>> 
>>> dictionary_tuples(a, graph)
[('11', '12'), ('11', '40'), ('11', '41'), ('11', '10')]
>>>
```

Or, if you only want to pass in the node:

```
def dictionary_tuples(key, values):
    return [(key, item) for item in values]
```

As such:

```
>>> def dictionary_tuples(key, values):
...     return [(key, item) for item in values]
... 
>>> graph = {'11': ['12','40','41','10'], '100': ['120','400','410','100'], '12':['11','13'], '13':['12']}
>>> a= '11'
>>> b = graph[a]
>>> dictionary_tuples(a, b)
[('11', '12'), ('11', '40'), ('11', '41'), ('11', '10')]
>>>
```

Comment: He's no passing the whole graph, even though I agree it may be more convenient that way

Comment: I don't need to pass the whole graph, I want to build the tuples for the current node

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension with a double loop:

```
[(key, elem) for key, value in graph.items() for elem in value]
```

Demo:

```
>>> graph = {'11': ['12','40','41','10'], '100': ['120','400','410','100'], '12':['11','13'], '13':['12']}
>>> [(key, elem) for key, value in graph.items() for elem in value]
[('11', '12'), ('11', '40'), ('11', '41'), ('11', '10'), ('100', '120'), ('100', '400'), ('100', '410'), ('100', '100'), ('12', '11'), ('12', '13'), ('13', '12')]
```

Answer (score -1):

As I said, you want a list as output, therefore you need to change your code with something like:

```
def dictionary_tuples(key, values):
    return list((key, value) for value in values)
```

Gives:

```
print dictionary_tuples(a,b)
[('11', '12'), ('11', '40'), ('11', '41'), ('11', '10')]
```

Comment: The OP asked for a list of **`tuples`**, so obviously, he does not want a list as output.

Comment: This does output tuples, all with the same key